# What are some good ways to store Analytics data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, analytics

What are some good ways to store Analytics data using MongoDB for future analysis?  I am thinking of doing something like:

```
> db.analytics.insert( { page: 'product', id: 123, date: new Date('Sept 8, 2010'),
                       pageviews: 222, timeOnPage: 5432 } )

> db.analytics.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c8e04b1f14d4366465197b8"), "page" : "product", "id" : 123, 
  "date" : "Wed Sep 08 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)", "pageviews" : 222, 
  "timeOnPage" : 5432 }
```

which is quite relational.  pageviews and timeOnPage can be lumped into

```
> db.analytics.insert({page: 'product', id: 123, date: new Date('Sept 8, 2010'),
                       data: { pageviews: 222, timeOnPage: 5432 } })
```

although if using Mongoid (a Rails Object Relation Mapper), then there is more complication for having an additional model.

Comment: wouldn't a relational database be better suited?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at using upserts and the $inc operator on counters. If pageviews increments you can use something like this (selector, operator, upsert set to true)

```
update( { page: 'product', id: 123, data: { pageviews: 222}) }, 
        { $inc : {  pageviews: 1} }, 
        { upsert : true } )
```

If no document exists for this record it will create one, if one exists it will increment the pageviews.

It really all depends on how your data is shaped.

This [blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/171353301/using-mongodb-for-real-time-analytics) explains more.